# Querying a 1-Many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, for simplicity I am going to illustrate with a simple question.

A Product table contains products definitions with two columns

```
Product ID -- Product Name
```

A Product Details table contains product details stored as vertical or extended properties

```
Product Detail ID -- Product Number -- Key ID -- Value ID
```

Assuming I have two other reference tables, one of them is for Keys and another for Values.

Keys Table

```
1 -- Price
2 -- Color
```

Values Table

```
1 -- Red
2 -- Blue
3 -- 10 $
4 -- 20$
```

I am using the Product Details table as a vertical table to add as many properties as I want for the product.

Now comes searching for records!

For instance, I need to get all Products whose "ALL" Product Details columns match.

I have the following data

Product Table Data

```
Prod#1   XXX
Prod#2   YYY
```

Product Details Table Data

```
1  Prod#1  1  4
2  Prod#1  2  1
```

Line #1: Product 1 having Price key with a value of 20$
Line #2: Product 1 having Color key with a value of Red

Now the following queries need to be executed:

```
1- Get Products with Key "Price" having a price > 10$
2- Get Products with a Key "Price" > 10 AND "Color" is Red
```

Is this doable in TSQL in a single Query?

Thanks

Comment: Given you have chosen this rather bizarre structure, why have you not created a key for product name?

Comment: Why bizarre? It's a dynamic way of allowing my client to add 1 or more extended properties on a single product, a kind of vertical database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select
  distinct p.product_id
from
  products p
  inner join product_details pd_price on p.product_id = pd_price.product_id
  inner join keys as k_price on pd_price.key_id = k_price.key_id
  inner join values as v_price on pd_price.value_id = v_price.value_id
  inner join product_details pd_color on p.product_id = pd_color.product_id
  inner join keys as k_color on pd_color.key_id = k_color.key_id
  inner join values as v_color on pd_color.value_id = v_color.value_id
where
  k_price.name = 'Price' and v_price.value > 10 and
  k_color.name = 'Color' and v_color.value = 'Red'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job with just 1 query, something like this:

```
SELECT Products.ProductId, Products.ProductName FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductDetails ON Products.ProductId = ProductDetails.ProductId
INNER JOIN Keys ON ProductDetails.KeyId = Keys.Id
INNER JOIN Values ON ProductDetails.ValueId = Values.Id
WHERE Keys.Name = 'Price' AND Values.Value > @Value
```

The problem is that data type of Values table, Value field has to be defined. If you choose string then you have to cast it to integer if you want to compare it to integer values.